# Check that JSON value has a string that matches certain values in Postman

Tags: api, rest, testing, postman

I'm trying to write tests to see if a service is OK, Unknown, or Unreachable via my API. However, all of my tests come back as having passed. I know that all my servers are in an "OK" state, though, and that none of them are "Unreachable" or "Unknown." I believe the "unknown" and "unreachable" tests should be failing. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the body of the response:

```
{
    "result": {
        "dhcpServers": [
            {
                "ref": "DHCPServers/4",
                "name": "unixdns",
                "address": "10.9.0.220",
                "resolvedAddress": "10.9.0.220",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "type": "ISC",
                "state": "OK",
                "security": "Unknown",
                "customProperties": {},
                "enabled": true,
                "dhcpv6": false
            },
            {
                "ref": "DHCPServers/15",
                "name": "mmappliance",
                "address": "10.9.0.156",
                "resolvedAddress": "10.9.0.156",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "type": "ISC",
                "state": "OK",
                "security": "Unknown",
                "customProperties": {},
                "enabled": true,
                "dhcpv6": false
            },
            {
                "ref": "DHCPServers/19",
                "name": "WIN-51",
                "proxy": "10.9.0.150",
                "address": "10.9.0.150",
                "resolvedAddress": "10.9.0.150",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "type": "MSDHCP",
                "state": "OK",
                "security": "Unknown",
                "customProperties": {},
                "enabled": true,
                "dhcpv6": true
            },
            {
                "ref": "DHCPServers/22",
                "name": "WIN-PM",
                "proxy": "10.9.0.100",
                "address": "10.9.0.100",
                "resolvedAddress": "10.9.0.100",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "type": "MSDHCP",
                "state": "OK",
                "security": "Unknown",
                "customProperties": {},
                "enabled": true,
                "dhcpv6": true
            }
        ],
        "totalResults": 4
    }
}
```

I've written the following tests:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('DHCP service is ok', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).to.have.body('OK')
    })
})


pm.test('DHCP service is Unknown', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).to.have.body('Unknown')
    })
})

pm.test('DHCP service is unreachable', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).to.have.body('Unreachable')
    })
})



//Unknown - DHCP Server Controller status is unknown.
//OK -  DHCP Server Controller and service are both OK.
//Unreachable - DHCP Server Controller is offline or otherwise unreachable.
//Out of date - DHCP Server Controller has a different version than Central.
//Updating -    DHCP Server Controller version is being updated.
//Uninitialized -   DHCP Server is on a uninitialized appliance that needs to be manually initialized.
//Detached -    DHCP Server has been detached without removing it from the system.
//DHCP Service Down -   DHCP Server service is down and DNS server is not responding to queries.
//DHCP Service Impaired -   DHCP Server service is running but impaired.
```

Answer (score 0):

- You miss one level to get `dhcpServers`. It should be `jsonData.result.dhcpServers`, not `jsonData.dhcpServers`,
- Use `.eql('OK')` instead of `.to.have.body('OK')`

The test would be:

```
pm.test('DHCP service is ok', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.result.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).eql('OK');
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, now all the tests fail. But the states are still "OK" on the response body. I changed it to this: 

let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('DHCP service is ok', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.result.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).to.have.body('OK')
    })
})


pm.test('DHCP service is Unknown', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.result.dhcpServers, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.state).to.have.body('Unknown')
    })
})